# How to setup Apache Archiva to use HTTPS instead of HTTP

Tags: https, archiva

In default configuration, Apache Archiva 2.2 uses HTTP, and [official documentation](https://archiva.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/) tells nothing how to change it to HTTPS.

I think that this can be done by modifying `conf/jetty.xml` file, but when I try to do this, as described in [Jetty documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-ssl.html#configuring-sslcontextfactory), it only gives me errors like:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: class org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.setTrustStorePath(class java.lang.String)
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: I"m not clear with Jetty maybe the Jetty documentation is not up2date or we use a too old version. Perso I use an Apache httpd server which proxy request to Archiva instance so it's easy to manage https HTH
Olivier

Comment: Thanks. I also thought about using Apache proxy as a workaround. I will try to write answer with exactly configuration when I figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used Apache as a HTTPS proxy, configuring new virtual host:

```
Listen 8081

<VirtualHost *:8081>
        ServerName archiva.example.com

        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile    /path/to/apache_certs/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/apache_certs/cert.key

        ProxyRequests     Off
        ProxyPass         /  http://localhost:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse  /  http://localhost:8080/
        <Proxy http://localhost:8080/*>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPreserveHost on
</VirtualHost>
```

Don't forget to enable two apache mods that are necessary to run this:

```sh
sudo a2enmod proxy proxy_http
```

Answer (score 1):

I added the following to `jetty.xml` and it worked:

```
<Call class="java.lang.System" name="setProperty"><Arg>jdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize</Arg><Arg>2048</Arg></Call>
<Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSelectChannelConnector">
            <Arg>
                <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.http.ssl.SslContextFactory">
                    <Set name="keyStore"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="." />/conf/tomcat.keystore</Set>
                    <Set name="keyStorePassword">changeit</Set>
                    <Set name="ExcludeProtocols">
                        <Array type="java.lang.String">
                            <Item>SSLv3</Item>
                        </Array>
                    </Set>
                </New>
            </Arg>
            <Set name="port">8843</Set>
            <Set name="maxIdleTime">30000</Set>
            <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
            <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
            <Set name="lowResourcesConnections">5000</Set>
            <Set name="lowResourcesMaxIdleTime">5000</Set>
            <Set name="IncludeCipherSuites">
                <Array type="java.lang.String">
                    <Item>TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384</Item>
                    <Item>TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256</Item>
                    <Item>TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384</Item>
                    <Item>TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256</Item>
                    <Item>TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384</Item>
                    <Item>TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
                    <Item>TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256</Item>
                    <Item>TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
                    <Item>TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA</Item>
                    <Item>TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA</Item>
                    <Item>TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA</Item>
                    <Item>TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA</Item>
                </Array>
            </Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</Call>
```